# Div positioning - putting one after another

Tags: css, html

Imagine a math problem on the web. I would like to display the math problem and then have the user be able to type their answer to the right of it. I am trying to set up the  structure. I have custom buttons that I will use to change the inner text of the answer.

The math problem is given by `"problemtext"` and the answer is given by `"problemanswer"`. When the user taps on the number pad, I will place that number in the `"problemanswer"` segment.

The problem with this set up is that the answer is showing up below the problem.

[image]

**But I want the answer to be directly to the right of the problem, *not below it***. **Further, I'd like the answer to have a box (or border) around it.** How can I do this? What should my html/css look like?

```
<div id="problem" class="text" style="display:none">
    <div id="problemoverall" align="center">
        <div id="problemtext" style="font: bold 65px Arial;">
        </div>
        <div id="problemanswer" style="font: bold 65px Arial;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's some relevant CSS I have

```
.text {
text-align:center;
font-size:16px; 
line-height: 165%;
color:#f1f1f1;
}

.text p {
margin: 8px 0;
}
```

Comment: inline or inline-block is the way to go.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `display: inline;`. Add this css rule:

```
#problemtext, #problemanswer{    
    display: inline;
}
```

Have a look:
http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/dPSav/1/